# Tomcat server not working anymore after a stop and restart

Tags: java, spring, war, jmx, tomcat8

I've got an error related to tomcat server. I shut down my server (took a while) and then when a start the server back, an error appears :

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [com.amadeus.security.CCDVAccess@2a9cce4a] with key 'CCDVAccess'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.amadeus.security:name=CCDVAccess
org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:795)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:632)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1627)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:830)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:639)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:873)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:806)
sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know that the error is not related to the code, because nothing change. 
I try

- to stop and restart many times,
- to change the version of the WAR I was using.
- to delete the logs and the folder work/catalina

I do not know what else I should try, so I hope some of you has I idea about that. I really think the issue is coming from tomcat but I'm not sure.

Thank for your help
Sébastien

**Edit:** I solved my issue it was a stupid mistake. I did a backup of my WAR file without changing the extension... Therefore tomcat was launching 2 identicals servers.
Thanks guys for your help

Comment: Try to delete your exploded war file and clear your temp and work directories. Then Maybe something went wrong when shutting down your application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have two Spring Boot apps in the same JVM so you need to segregate the MBean namespace.
the first log error tell you that.

> org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable
>   to register MBean [com.amadeus.security.CCDVAccess@2a9cce4a] with key
>   'CCDVAccess'; nested exception is
>   javax.management.***InstanceAlreadyExistsException***:
>   com.amadeus.security:name=CCDVAccess

for further clarification 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/118.