# Cannot undeployed tomcat 8.5.4 application

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I got a previous problem with Tomcat ([Here is the link if that can be of any help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807202/tomcat-server-not-working-anymore-after-a-stop-and-restart)). Now I have 2 applications running, one called "name1" and the second "name2". The thing is that I have only one war file called "name2".
On tomcat manager page, I see both applications. I cannot undeployed the "name1" but I can for the "name2".

[image: screenshot Apache manager page]

On the webapps folder I have only a folder and war file related to the application "name2"
On the wtpwebapps folder I have a folder related to the application "name1"

When I stop the application "name1" change the name of the folder in wtpwebapps, stop and restart tomcat, the serveur wont start and throw the error saying that he cannot copy the application from "/wtpwebapps/name1" to "/temp"

I tried to stop this application, stop the server, remove "/work/catalina/" remove logs, and start it again, but the application is still deployed.

I also add in the context.xml the following attributes:

```
<Context autoDeploy="true" antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

But no luck.
What I want to do, It's to rename "name2" application as "name1" but as an application of that name still exist, it's not possible. If you can help me to remove the application "name1" or rename it, I take it.

Thanks

> Edit: On the Server.xml the path to the application name1 was defined. I remove it and everything work fine now. Thanks *Exception_al*

Comment: What about your server.xml ... do you have a `<Context` definition there for your application ?

Comment: Oh yes there is  <Context docBase="F:\Programs\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\wtpwebapps\name1" path="/name1" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:name1"/>, I'll check what I need with that, thanks!!

Comment: Getting rid of the context should do the trick ! Cheers ! You could post your server.xml context section if you wish, and I could post an answer if it helps :) !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot it did the trick